# React native button in top right of image with contain resize mode

Tags: react-native

I have a portrait image with it's resizeMode set to contain so it scales to the screen. I'd like to place a button in the top right hand side of the image. My problem is that because the image scales differently on different screen resolutions, the button is placed differently when I try to use absolute positioning. Is there a simple way of doing this in React Native? Do I need to use a responsive positioning library?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Image
       source={require('../image/path...jpg')} 
       style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
    />
    <Icon 
       name="md-close" 
       style={{position: 'absolute', right: 5,top: 5}} />
</View>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me unfortunately. It puts the icon in the top right of the screen. I need the icon in the top right of the image (which is scaled different on each screen because I'm using resizeMode="contain")